# Sharing a public link to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've solved the problem below, but I've added this in case it helps someone.

Our tennis club uses a Google Calendar to show the court bookings. I want to have a URL to show the bookings for today. In the Calendar Settings, in the Integrate Calendar section, you can create a Public link to the calendar. This shows the whole month's entries.

To show just a day's entries, you can add "&mode=day" to the URL. Bizarrely, this then shows yesterday's entries. After much searching, I found this solution to the problem, supplied by Neil@GCalToolkit: https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/32927857/mode-day-shows-the-previous-date-on-a-public-calendar-link?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: add a Date range to the URL: ...&mode=DAY&dates=20010101/20301231